# Same message being retried and not sent to dlq

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have defined a queue - blah.queue and have defined the dead-letter-routing-key for it. However, when I have a poison message which fails with a Exception, the same message is requeued and reattempted (in an infinite loop).
I would expect that after 3 retries, the message should be put on the exchange with the dead-letter-routing-key. But that doesn't seem to be happening.

I have the following settings:

```
    <rabbit:queue name="blah.queue" auto-delete="false" durable="true">
    <rabbit:queue-arguments>
        <entry key="x-dead-letter-exchange" value="" />
        <entry key="x-dead-letter-routing-key" value="blah.queue.dlq.route" />
        <entry key="x-ha-policy" value="all" />
    </rabbit:queue-arguments>
</rabbit:queue>
<rabbit:direct-exchange name="${rabbit.idesk.exchange}">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="blah.queue" key="blah.route" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>

<bean id="myConsumer" class="com.ankit.CustomConsumer" />

<bean id="myConsumerMessageListenerAdapter" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg ref="myConsumer" />
    <constructor-arg ref="myMessageConverter" />
</bean>

<bean id="myConsumerMessageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="queueNames" value="blah.queue" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="queueConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myConsumerMessageListenerAdapter" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="loggingErrorHandler" />
    <property name="adviceChain">
        <list>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="loggingErrorHandler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils.LoggingErrorHandler" />

<bean id="myMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter">
    <property name="classMapper">
        <bean class="com.ankit.queue.mapper.NamedClassMapper">
            <constructor-arg
                value="com.ankit.dto.EventDTO" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="createMessageIds" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="retryAdvice" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageRecoverer" ref="rejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer" />
    <property name="retryOperations" ref="retryTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
    <property name="retryPolicy" ref="simpleRetryPolicy" />
    <property name="backOffPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.FixedBackOffPolicy">
            <property name="backOffPeriod" value="5000" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="simpleRetryPolicy" class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
    <property name="maxAttempts" value="3" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you not see the WARN message from the recoverer?

```
@Override
public void recover(Message message, Throwable cause) {
    if (this.logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
        this.logger.warn("Retries exhausted for message " + message, cause);
    }
    throw new ListenerExecutionFailedException("Retry Policy Exhausted",
                new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(cause), message);
}
```

Turn on DEBUG logging to watch the retry behavior.

Comment: It seems it never lands here. I enabled debug logs for the Retrytemplate too. It seems that the retry count gets reset to 0  `DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate (RetryTemplate.java:281) - Retry: count=0<br/>
Exception<br/>
DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate (RetryTemplate.java:320) - Checking for rethrow: count=1<br/>
DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate (RetryTemplate.java:326) - Rethrow in retry for policy: count=1<br/>
Exception<br/>
DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate (RetryTemplate.java:281) - Retry: count=0`

Comment: If I change the retryPolicy to NeverRetryPolicy. I can see that the control flows in here. Any idea why the retry context count might not get incremented for the SimpleRetryPolicy?

Comment: I just copied the config above and it works fine for me; you are using stateful retry - do your inbound messages have the `message_id` property set? (required for stateful). During retries, I see `2018-10-15 16:56:17.154 DEBUG 49667 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Rejecting messages (requeue=true)
`. After the retries are exhausted, I see `2018-10-15 16:56:17.157 DEBUG 49667 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Rejecting messages (requeue=false)` and it goes to the DLQ.

Comment: Yes.. the incoming messages on the queue do have a message_id set on them.

Comment: Post the full DEBUG log someplace (github gist, pastebin etc).